# Best way to initialize read only objects in junits

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have a read-only class that will be initialized by Jackson. I will be giving out the jar to be used by an API, and don't want the user to set properties to the object.

```
class ReadOnlyClass {
    private String value;
    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Now this object has to be passed to another service to do some other work.

I want to write Junits for this service. How do I initialize this object.

I've heard using reflection is a bad practice. Is there any utility in powermock/mockito or any other library that I can use.

Comment: Make `value` final, write a constructor which sets the `value`. Also check Lombok.

Comment: creating a constructor can allow the user of api to create their own object and enter their own value. I don't want to allow this.

Comment: How is the object initialised in the application?

Comment: Via Jackson objectmapper.readvalue

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any utility in powermock/mockito or any other library that I can use.

This way it should work,

```
class SomeService{
    public void doSomeTask(ReadOnlyClass roc){
      // Some logic
    }

}

class SomeServiceTest{

   @Mock
   private ReadOnlyClass readOnlyClass;

@autowired
   private SomeService someService;

   @Test
   public void testDoSomeTask(){
      when(readOnlyClass.getValue())
                .thenReturn("some value");
      someService.doSomeTask(readOnlyClass);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create constructor if you can modify ReadOnlyClass.
2. You can prepare json and deserialize it using Jackson